# How can I add bootstrap styles to my django form?

Tags: python, html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I created a django form and output it in template. But I can't understand how I can add bootstrap styles 'cause this django form isn't good.

Image of output:

[image]

Code:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}
    Contact Us
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Contact Us</h1>
<form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {% for field in form %}
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ field.label }}
                {{ field }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button">Send</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add bootstrap styling to your form, you're going to need to paste this code somewhere between your  tags for the CSS;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

And this for the JavaScript;

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

This will apply some styling to your form.
Once you've done this, you'll have to use the classes that are specified on the BootStrap documentation that you can find here if you want to change the styling: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/

This should give you the styling that you want although you may want to add a bit of your own additionally to get exactly what you're after.

Comment: You need to make your question clearer, my answer tells you how you can use bootstrap which is how your question comes across as. If you're looking to improve it, you're going to have to combine Bootstrap with your own knowledge of CSS. Bootstrap will give you some basic styling but it is up to you as well.

Comment: I need to style my form as https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/media/2017/08/bs4-form-2.png

Comment: That's a picture of your form. Where is your stylesheet? You can't expect anyone to give you the help you need without posting the relevant code.

Comment: It seems to me like you haven't tried adding any styling to it and you just want someone to write the code for you. Mess around with some CSS and come back with some valid attempts before asking for help.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your form:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for myField in self.fields:
        self.fields[myField].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```